# Html5 history api, any method to check the 1 forward history

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I read to go forward +1 in the history, we have api method: window.history.go(1);

Is there any method just to check history and not reload page the page with it?

Comment: looking at the properties of the history object I'm afraid not. But maybe someone knows a way.

Comment: there is no such function provided by History API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.referrer` API to get the last one.

Comment: Its giving me empty string "".

Comment: not even on chrome for me. may be i am doing something wrong. please tell me steps where i can get non-empty.